# CSS: define animations inline without a separate `keyframes` class

Tags: css

[Generally](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) you would define a onHover animation of a `square` class like this:

```
.square:hover {
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-name: square_hover;
}

@keyframes square_hover {
  to {background-color: yellow;}
}
```

Is there a way to define it like this:

```
.square:hover {
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation: {
    to { background-color: yellow; }
  };
}

@keyframes square_hover
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MDN the correct way of declaring an animation is using this syntax:

```
@keyframes <keyframes-name> {
  <keyframe-block-list>
}
```

And then call it back using animation properties:

```
animation-duration: time;
animation-name: animation;
```

Where you will  is a string that will identify the animation name. And  is the sequence you will follow to create the animation.

So in short, CSS has a strict syntax you have to follow. **But** it seems like you're trying to find a simpler way to declare/create **animation on hover**.

You can simply get rid of the animation and directly add the properties you want to change **on hover**. For instance, if you want to change the background colour of the square class you will simply start with the initial state/base styles:

```
.square {
  background-color: black;
}
```

And then apply the styles you want to change:

```
.square:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

And if you want smooth out the transition simply add the **transition** property to the base styles. And the syntax looks something like

```
transition: property-to-transition time ease;
```

A working example:

```
.square {
  background-color: black;
  transition: background-color .5s ease;
}
```

References:

MDN Docs @keyframes: [@keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes#formal_syntax)

MDN Docs transitions: [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#examples)

MDN Docs animations: [animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)